# tr:hover shade effect overlay on bootstrap dropdown menu button

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I want to put bootstrap button in a column of table row, which has a hover shade effect.
Please see the live demo here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/T9QHw/47/

Unfortunately, it seems like the shade effect conflict to menu list. However, when I change the hover effect opacity to 1.0, it seems working well. But I want to keep the opacity at 0.45.

Thank you for advance help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to have the bootstrap dropdownlist or combobox however you want to call it have a hover shade effect. I have looked at the fiddle you posted. As I understand the bootstrap function has the shade effect built-in but you have added an extra shade effect with this:

```
tr:hover{
background:#b1b1b1;
    opacity: 0.45;

}​
```

just delete the above css and only the dropdownlist will have the shade effect

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry if my question is not clear. Yes, the button has shade effect itself, but there is nothing to do with this issue.

What I really want to do is I strongly want to keep tr:hover effect meanwhile the existing functions on bootstrap button are still working.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: if you don't want to change the tr:hover effect then you have to change the opacity of the bootstrap css. if you don't want to do that either, there's nothing else to do

Comment: Could you please try to change the opacity to 1.0? The result is what  I want but I want to have transparent hover effect instead of solid color.